# Using Rasterio to index by traditional longitude and latitude with Molleweide Projection GeoTIFF

Tags: python, raster, geotiff-tiff, rasterio

I'm currently trying to read carbon footprint information from a GeoTIFF, I've never worked with geographic data before.

The link is http://worldmrio.com/citiesmaps/GGMCF_v1.0.tif

I was wondering how I would index the nd-array with longitude and latitude values that I've scraped for some cities. What I want is the actual value at each longitude and latitude.

Additionally, would there be a problem with the projection format?

`print(dataset.crs)`

gives me

```
PROJCS["World_Mollweide",GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS    84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Mollweide"],PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],PARAMETER["false_easting",0],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AXIS["Northing",NORTH]]
{'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[(-18040095.3812882, 9020047.84316439), (-18040095.3812882, -9020047.84316439), (18040095.3812882, -9020047.84316439), (18040095.3812882, 9020047.84316439), (-18040095.3812882, 9020047.84316439)]]}
```

Comment: Duplicate of: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/358058/144357

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extracting data from a raster](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/358036/extracting-data-from-a-raster)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to reproject your lon, lats to the Mollweide CRS (or reproject your raster to EPSG:4326 which may not be the best option).

There's numerous ways to reproject your coords, (geopandas, pyproj) the example below uses [`fiona.transform`](https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona/blob/master/fiona/transform.py).

To extract the raster values at your coordinates, you can use [`rasterio.sample`](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.sample.html).

For example:

```
import fiona.transform
import rasterio.sample

def reproject_coords(src_crs, dst_crs, coords):
    xs = [c[0] for c in coords]
    ys = [c[1] for c in coords]
    xs, ys = fiona.transform.transform(src_crs, dst_crs, xs, ys)
    return [[x,y] for x,y in zip(xs, ys)]


with rasterio.open('/tmp/b1_moll.tif') as dataset:
    src_crs = 'EPSG:4326'
    dst_crs = dataset.crs.to_proj4()  # '+proj=moll +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m no_defs'
    # dst_crs = dataset.crs.to_wkt()  # 'PROJCS["World_Mollweide",GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS    84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Mollweide"],PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],PARAMETER["false_easting",0],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AXIS["Northing",NORTH]]'


    coords = [[123.456, -34.567]]  # [longitude, latitude] not [lat, lon]...
    new_coords = reproject_coords(src_crs, dst_crs, coords)

    values = list(rasterio.sample.sample_gen(dataset, new_coords))

    for (lon, lat), value in zip(coords, values):
        print(lon, lat, value[0])  # value[0] == band 1 value at lon, lat
```

Comment: This should  be the solution. The dataset did not match my expectations however.

Comment: @EwinZuo What do you mean. I just downloaded the raster, picked some coords in US & Australia and the results were correct. Don't forget coordinate order in GIS software is x,y i.e longitude, latitude not lat, lon.

Answer (score 3):

The above solution used to work pretty good, but the transformation of coordinates from one system to another has been modified (I think Fiona doesn't even include it anymore).

Best thing is to use pyproj Transformer, as shown below.

```
import rasterio as rio
from pyproj import Transformer
with rio.open(tif) as dataset:
    examples = [(52.2271, 4.9013), (52.3778, 4.8816)]
    transformer = Transformer.from_crs("epsg:4326", dataset.crs)
    coords = [transformer.transform(x, y) for x,y in examples]
```

Read more on how to best do this here: https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/gotchas.html#upgrading-to-pyproj-2-from-pyproj-1. Hope this helps!

Comment: I would avoid using `to_proj4` https://proj.org/faq.html#what-is-the-best-format-for-describing-coordinate-reference-systems. I recommend instead passing in the `rasterio.CRS` object directly as it is supported by pyproj https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/crs_compatibility.html#converting-from-rasterio-crs-crs-to-pyproj-crs-crs.

Comment: See: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/358058/144357

Comment: @snowman2 looks good, I've modified it to feed the crs-object directly. Sometimes I'm surprised how Python "just works"!